# Number of $4\times K$ board arrangements such that there exist no square of size 2 having all black cells

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose a person has a board of size 4 x K and each cell of this board can either be black or white. The person and his girlfriend come to a conclusion that they don’t like black squares. We decide to arrange the board in a way that they like it.We need to find the number of boards of dimension 4 x K such that it does not contain any square of size 2 such that all cells are black.

So we need to find the number of arrangements in terms of **K** .

How do I ensure that no square of size 2 have all black cells in any arrangement ?

Answer (score 1):

Tricky question. Maybe we have to divide it by cases, choosing based on the previous row.

First row, free choice, $2^4=16$ options. However - not so quick! - we need to divide into cases to allow calculation for the next row:

- $1$ option all black ($B_4$)
- $2$ options with $3$ black cells together ($B_3$)
- $1$ options with $2$ black cells together in the middle ($B_C$)
- $4$ options with $2$ black cells together at the edge ($B_E$)
- $8$ options with no black cells adjacent ($B_0$)

Subsequent rows then depend  on the state of the preceeding row as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \text{Row }n\text{ state}\to  &B_4&B_3&B_C&B_E&B_0\\
\ \text{Row }n+1\text{ state}  \\
\hline B_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline B_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline B_C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline B_E & 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline B_0 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

This defines a transition matrix that we can use to derive the options to get to the various cases or states for a particular row from the row before.

This allows us to drive a calculation forward as required:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline   \text{ Row } K \to & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
         State  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline  B_4 & 1 & 8 & 128 & 1728 & 24256 & 337408 & 4703360 \\
\hline  B_3 & 2 & 20 & 304 & 4152 & 58128 & 809072 & 11276608 \\
\hline  B_C & 1 & 12 & 176 & 2424 & 33872 & 471664 & 6573248 \\
\hline  B_E & 4 & 48 & 696 & 9616 & 134256 & 1869888 & 26058016 \\
\hline  B_0 & 8 & 128 & 1728 & 24256 & 337408 & 4703360 & 65531136 \\
\hline  \text{Total options} & 16 & 216 & 3032 & 42176 & 587920 & 8191392 & 114142368 \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

Comment: The numbers after $K=3$ aren’t quite right, but the first three were enough to let me discover that this is [OEIS A$181247$](http://oeis.org/A181247), which begins $16,216,3032,42176,587920,8191392,114142368$. There’s almost no information in the OEIS entry; there is a recursion, $a_n=10a_{n-1}+54a_{n-2}+16a_{n-3}-64a_{n-4}$, but it’s described as ‘empirical’, so I assume that it’s not actually been proved.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - thanks - hmm, I'll check what the issue is then. I think my transition matrix is OK; it's strange that it would be right for a few and then wrong. I was thinking about writing a little more on this anyway.

Comment: In all honesty I didn’t look at the matrix: I was hoping that OEIS would have useful information as a shortcut! It looks like you’re off by $8$, $160$, $3232$, and $57568$, in case that helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I figured it out, I changed $B_C$ and $B_E$ midway through assessment. I didn't think taht you were checking the matrix though from your remarks, just happy you looked it over and spotted there was a problem